# How to change fetch API link for deployment?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

This is a method to fetch data from an API. I have used the MERN stack. I hosted this application on Heroku. The problem is that  I can't understand how to change the link to fetch the API because on Heroku the app is running at a different port every time.

```
const SendData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await fetch('http://localhost:4000/Login',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    Email,
                    Password
                })
            })

            .then(HandleErrs)
            .then((res) => {
                
               return res


            }).then((res)=>{
                const {UserName}=res;
                // console.log(UserName);
                setCredentials({
                    UserName,
                    Email,
                    Password
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                getErr(ERR);
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
```

Comment: Use some kind of config which you switch for each build/deployment. You might be interested in [dot.env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will not give a direct answer to your question, but its a good practice,

What we normally do is create a separate file for api details

for ex:

api.js

```
  //REACT_APP_SERVER_URL is a env variable in .env file
  const rootUri = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
    ? process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
    : 'http://localhost:3001';

  const apiVersion = 'v1';
  const apiBasePath = `${rootUri}/api/${apiVersion}`; //this is the base path

  export const userApis = {
    all: {
      url: `${apiBasePath}/users`,
      method: 'GET',
    },
    update: {
      url: `${apiBasePath}/user`,
      method: 'POST',
    },
  };
```

this is how we use it

```
const fetchAllUser = () => {
    const api = userApis.all;
    fetch(api.url, {
        method: api.url.method,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    }...
```

Comment: You can use `const rootUri = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:3001'` rather than a ternary